# Vue.js: v-for behaves different with template literals

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, template-literals

Why does `v-for` behave different when using either `numbers` or `template literals`?

Here is an example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <p>Result with template literal</p>
  <ul>
    <li
      v-for="pages in `${2+2}`" 
      :key="pages"
    >
      <p>{{pages}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <p>Result with straight number</p>
  <ul>
    <li
      v-for="pages in 4" 
      :key="pages"
    >
      <p>{{pages}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not the same. In the first one, you are using `v-for` on a string. In which case, vue will loop through the characters and display each of them in a `li`. In the second one, it's an integer. In which case, vue will use the [range](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range) mechanism

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <p>Result with template literal</p>
  <ul>
   <!--Displays 1, 0, 0-->
    <li
      v-for="pages in `100`" 
      :key="pages"
    >
      <p>{{pages}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <p>Result with straight number</p>
  <ul>
    <li
      v-for="pages in 4" 
      :key="pages"
    >
      <p>{{pages}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to convert it into a `Number` ? Because my actual use case look something like this: `v-for="pages in ${Math.round(transactions[0].total_pages)}"` (template literals are not shown here in the comments section)

Comment: @saitam just remove the `${}` wrapper. `Math.round` returns an integer